# how to visualize images in debug console when im using vscode via remote ssh

Tags: python-3.x, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote, x11-forwarding

I am using **vscode remote ssh** and connect to my server (a node in a cluster) via ssh.
My local machine is Windows and my Host is ubuntu.
My vscode is being used to code in python.

I am trying for weeks to be able to run a python code and display images in the **debug console** like what we do in the normal terminal or in jupyter notebook, but I notice that I cannot display the image in the debug console at all.
here is a toy example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img =  np.random.rand(300,200)
plt.imshow(img);plt.show()
```

basically when I try to do `plt.imshow(img);plt.show()` in the debug console I either get nothing or I get `qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display localhost:0.0 Could not connect to any X display.` .
I tried several methods such as using x11 extenson or adding x11 forwarding in the putty or add Display in the `launch.json`. However, none of them works.

I am coming to the conclusion that vscode remote ssh and debug console in python dont have that feature yet. But if you know a way to do it PLEASE let me know.

I hope that I am clear that displaying image in the normal situation is working and it is not working in the debug situation.
Please note that when I am doing the debug I dont want to display the image out side of the debug console.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

it seems you have done the first steps of my proposed solution.

1. open your settings in vscode with ctrl+, and search for `terminal.integrated.env.linux`. Click Edid settings.json
2. Update `terminal.integrated.env.linux` to this

```
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "DISPLAY": "localhost:10.0",
  }
```

3. Shut down vscode
4. Open ssh conncetion to server with `ssh -X user@host`
5. Open vscode and use remote development add-on as usually.

Now, this will work indefinitely, just open the x11-forwarding on the side every time. The downside, for which I am currently searching for solution is that you need to remove the `"DISPLAY": "localhost:10.0"` every time you wish to develop locally, which is not optimal.

Edit: Since you are apparently using windows, you need to configure putty with X11 forwarding and use xming or other x11-forwarding software in place of my step 4.